How to create unique and independent preview deployment for each pull request for a web app in azure?
I want to create a preview deployment for each pull request in Azure like what Vercel did for a NextJS application.
I created a Web App service and deployed it with Docker ( container ) in Azure and it has this template name :
https://appname-dev-preview.azurewebsites.net/
and I have this pipeline:

trigger: none

variables:
  dockerRegistryServiceConnection: "rsc"
  imageRepository: "app-preview"
  containerRegistry: "company-name.azurecr.io"
  dockerfilePath: "$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/Dockerfile.prod"
  tag: "$(Build.BuildId)"
  vmImageName: "ubuntu-latest"

pool:
  vmImage: $(vmImageName)

stages:
  - stage: UnitComponentTests
    displayName: "Test Units & Components"
    jobs:
      - job: UnitComponentTestsJob
        displayName: "Run Unit and Component Tests"
        steps:
          - script: |
              npm install
              npm run test
            displayName: "Run Unit and Component Tests"

  - stage: E2ETests
    displayName: "Run E2E Tests"
    jobs:
      - job: E2ETestsJob
        displayName: "Run E2E Tests"
        steps:
          - script: |
              npm install
              npx playwright install
              npm run test-e2e
            displayName: "Run E2E Tests"
                      
  - stage: Build
    displayName: Build
    jobs:
      - job: Build
        displayName: Build
        pool:
          vmImage: $(vmImageName)
        steps:
          - task: Docker@2
            displayName: Build and push an image to container registry
            inputs:
              command: buildAndPush
              repository: $(imageRepository)
              dockerfile: $(dockerfilePath)
              buildContext: "./"
              containerRegistry: $(dockerRegistryServiceConnection)
              tags: |
                $(tag)
                latest




For each pull request, a new image was deployed to Azure and I was able to see the preview.
However, the problem is the next pull request overrides the previous one and the changes that appear in the preview deployment environment are from the last opened pull request.
How to create a unique URL for each PR?

It's not possible to generate a unique URL for each PR directly in Azure Web Apps. However, you can achieve this by deploying each pull request to a separate deployment slot, which will provide a unique URL for each PR.


How to create a unique URL for each PR?

Unlike Vercel, it is not possible to get a unique URL for each pull request in Azure Web Apps.
You have two options to get the unique URLs for each PR.

Create new web apps dynamically for each PR.
Creating a new deployment slot for each PR.

Since creating a new web app each time is not effective, it’s better to use deployment slots.

You can switch with the main slot easily with below command

az webapp deployment slot swap --name <app_name> --resource-group <resource_group> --slot <slot_name> --target-slot <target_slot_name>

You can create deployment slot via below command via Azure CLI
az webapp deployment slot create --name <app_name> --resource-group <resource_group> --slot <slot_name>


Please refer this docfor better understanding about deployment slots in DevOps pipeline.

Here you'll get a unique URL for each deployment slot.


How can I create a new slot from the pipeline?

Hi @AlaEddineMenai, in your pipeline, you can add an Azure CLI task to run the az webapp deployment slot create command to create a deployment slot.

But how to delete them after I merge the pull request with dev?

Hi  @AlaEddineMenai, you can delete deployment slots after merging the pull request by adding an Azure CLI task to run the az webapp deployment slot delete command.
